# SQL Server 2019 random number per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make a calculated column in SQL Server 2019 Express that will provide the SAME random number in multiple rows per same group/category. The random number I need between the group count range. Any good idea?

Also, the GroupCount is not a saved column but it is using

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION GROUP BY)
```

Example

```
ID - Group - GroupCount - RandomNum
-----------------------------------
1  - A     - 1          - 2
2  - A     - 2          - 2
3  - A     - 3          - 2
4  - A     - 4          - 2
5  - B     - 1          - 3
6  - B     - 2          - 3
7  - B     - 3          - 3
8  - C     - 1          - 2
9  - C     - 2          - 2
10 - C     - 3          - 2
11 - D     - 1          - 5
12 - D     - 2          - 5
13 - D     - 3          - 5
14 - D     - 4          - 5
15 - D     - 5          - 5
```

Comment: I note that in your example groups `A` and `C` have the same value for `RandomNum`; is that intended/desired?

Comment: First rule of coding is attention to detail. Your copied `ROW_NUMBER()` is just one big syntax error.

Comment: Does the number need to be truly random or just different for each group?

Comment: @Larnu,yes it is on purpose as the random number is per group. I made the example like that on purpose.

Comment: @MatBailie,for simplification I've excluded the columns which I am partitioning and the group. Why is the syntax wrong? I am getting count as expected already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code should do the trick:

- Take `ABS(CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) AS bigint))` this gives a random number between 0 and MaxValue
- Take the average of that over the group, this ensures we only get one value per group
- Take the min and max of the `Group` column + 1
- Modulo division between these two gives you a number between 0 and one less than that difference
- Add back the minimum

```sql
ABS(
  AVG(
    CAST(CHECKSUM(NEWID()) AS bigint)
  ) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group])
) % ( MAX(GroupCount) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group]) - MIN(GroupCount) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group]) + 1)
   + MIN(GroupCount) OVER (PARTITION BY [Group])
```

Comment: When I've implemented this, I got the GroupCount numbers in random order. Did I do something wrong or that is what your code meant to do?. I need the same number over a group just that number needs to be between that group count.

Comment: OK,This seems closer as it gives number per group it just occasionally I am getting this: Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.

Comment: If you put the cast inside the `AVG` like I have done now does it work?

Comment: It does, marking as answer. Thank you for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

`DENSE_RANK()` isn't random but it is a unique number per group:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over (order by [Group])
from t;
```

Is that sufficient?

EDIT:

Probably the simplest method is `JOIN` if you really need random numbers:

```
select t.*, randnum
from t join
     (select [Group],
             row_number() over (order by newid()) as randnum
      from t
      group by [Group]
     ) tt
     on t.[Group] = tt.[Group];
```

Comment: Need random number between the numbers from the GroupCount. Example, in the group A there is numbers from 1-4,therefore I need random number from 1-4 in the whole group.